# Insert or Update rows Via XML in SQL Server (Bulk)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Hi I Can not seem to wrap my head around how to parse an Xml document and the decide if it needs inserting or updating.

I Have an existing procedure that loks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SavePrice]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@Groupid varchar(150), @Price varchar(150), @CustomerID varchar(150)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF (EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.Prices WHERE groupid = @Groupid AND CustomerID = @CustomerID))
    UPDATE 
        dbo.Prices
    SET 
        price = @Price
    WHERE
        groupid = @Groupid 
    AND
        CustomerID = @CustomerID;

ELSE
    INSERT INTO 
        dbo.Prices
    (
        price,
        groupid,
        customerid
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @price,
        @groupid,
        @customerid
    );
End
```

Now I Would like this to run this in bulk preferably from an XML Argument

XML

```
<ArrayOfPrice xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Price>
  <Undergroup>111</Undergroup> 
  <Gain>10</Gain> 
  <CustomerID>14001099</CustomerID> 
  </Price>
  </ArrayOfPrice>
```

Something like this

```
foreach(Row r in XmlDoc)
{    
    Procedure(r)
}
```

I'm sorry but I really suck at SQL (which is why the above is written in pseudo C#), so I really hope you can help me. 
Any ideas?

Regards Kenneth

**EDIT**

The Solution was not to use XML to pass the bulk data, but a TableParameter

TableType

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[PriceDataType] As Table
(
--This type has structure similar to the DB table 
GroupID varchar(50) Not Null,
Price varchar(50) Not Null,
CustomerID varchar(50) Not Null
)
```

Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SavePrice]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @Dt PriceDataType READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

MERGE Prices AS Prices
    USING (SELECT * FROM @Dt) AS Source
    ON (Prices.GroupId = Source.GroupId) AND (Prices.CustomerId= Source.CustomerId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Prices.Price = Source.Price
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (Price, GroupId, CustomerId)
        VALUES (Source.Price, Source.GroupId, Source.CustomerId);
End
```

C#

```
        public void SavePrices(Price[] prices)
        {


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SavePrice", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            conn.Open();


            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Dt", SqlDbType.Structured));
            cmd.Parameters["@Dt"].Value = GetTableFromList(prices);

            cmd.ExecuteScalar();


            conn.Close();
            cmd.Dispose();


        }


        private DataTable GetTableFromList(Price[] ps)
        {
            DataTable tbl = new DataTable("PriceDataType");
            tbl.Columns.Add("GroupID", typeof(string));
            tbl.Columns.Add("Price", typeof(string));
            tbl.Columns.Add("CustomerID", typeof(string));

            foreach (Price p in ps)
                tbl.Rows.Add(p.Undergroup, p.Gain, p.CustomerID);
            return tbl;
        }
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you just looking for advice on how to write the stored procedure or also on how to interrogate your XML document with C#?

Comment: Just the stored procedure i have the C# covered

Comment: I added a MERGE example for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using SQL Server 2008, instead of building your stored procedure with an if block you can utilize the `MERGE` statement to perform an INSERT or UPDATE depending on the existence of a record.  There is MSDN [documentation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx&rct=j&q=t-sql%20merge&ei=B7aNTu2_LOnksQLD8MGcAQ&usg=AFQjCNEF51hFOMr_TFKuERBV5M56sor1lA&sig2=ENXcvH7pl4uKg3hPde9kuA&cad=rja) on utilizing the statement.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of what your MERGE statement could look like:

```
MERGE Prices AS Prices
    USING (SELECT @GroupId, @CustomerId) AS Source
    ON (Prices.GroupId = Source.GroupId) AND (Prices.CustomerId= Source.CustomerId)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Prices.Price = @Price
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT (Price, GroupId, CustomerId)
        VALUES (@Price, @GroupId, @CustomerId)
```

Also, if you want to truly insert your records in bulk, you could look into using a [table valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx).  If you have 5 "rows" from your XML document that you want to insert into your database, you can call your stored procedure 5 times by passing in the individual values (as you are currently doing).  By using the table valued parameter you could call your stored procedure once by handing it a table parameter and then utilize that table in your stored procedure.

Comment: That is very clever, but can you help me implement his with the xmlinput in the OP?

Comment: @Kenned - So you said your C# skills are covered, right?  What I'm suggesting is taking your XML document and getting it into a DataTable object.  Then (if you rework your stored procedure) you can pass that DataTable object to your stored procedure (see the documentation I linked to in my edit) and utilize it just as you would any other table (i.e. you can join to it, select from it, delete from it, etc).  The approach you take is up to you.  If you have quite a few "rows" in your XML document, you will get a performance boost by using the table parameter.

Comment: Thank you I didn't even know that you could pass a DataTable to a store procedure. I'll try that out

Comment: It works flawlessly thank you, BTW I added my solution to the OP

Comment: Great solution @Ek0nomik. Also I think if you wanted this to truly cover all bases with the MERGE statement you would need to factor in DELETION of rows that don't exist in the source during an update and this is only possible if you pass the data as a DataTable object so you have the full source and target for comparison. I'm currently implementing something very similar and the solution fell short of what I needed due to the DELETE operation also being a requirement, and the DataTable type saved me in combination with MERGE.